# How do I get my BCM43228 card working in mainline kernel 3.4 or higher?

Tags: drivers, kernel, broadcom, broadband

I followed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds to install kernel 3.4 and 3.5 from debs.

Unfortunately after booting I can't connect to the internet cause I have problems with my network device BCM43228. The proprietary driver cannot be activated.

Jockey logs have:

```
2012-07-08 22:13:06,796 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-07-08 22:13:06,854 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-07-08 22:13:06,873 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-07-08 22:13:08,843 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-07-08 22:13:12,818 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl
```

2012-07-08 22:13:12,819 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver

and trying to do:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

results in:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,151 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 314137 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bcmwl-kernel-source 5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6.1 (using .../bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.100.82.38+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-030500rc6-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.5.0-030500rc6-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.5.0-030500rc6-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.5.0-030500rc6-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.100.82.38+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-030500rc6-generic
```

Is there any support for this driver in linux >= 3.4?

Comment: For 16.04 all you need to do is make sure restricted drivers are checked in your software and updates sources and issue the command `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the wiki, might I draw your attention to this bit:

> By definition the mainline kernel builds are made from virgin unaltered mainline kernel sources and therefore do not, and should not, include any Ubuntu patches or drivers. *There are also no binary drivers for these kernels.*

Rather than the mainline builds, you will usually have better luck with the kernels for the next alpha/beta version (in this case, 12.10 Quantal Alpha 2), which should have binary drivers available:

1. Get the 12.10 `bcmwl-kernel-source` package from the below link and try installing it with `dpkg`:

   ```
   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112%2bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. If that doesn't work on your mainline build, install the 12.10 3.5 kernel images/headers, and then try again:

   ```
   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.5.0-4_3.5.0-4.4_all.deb
   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.5.0-4-generic_3.5.0-4.4_amd64.deb
   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.5.0-4-generic_3.5.0-4.4_amd64.deb
   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.5.0-4-generic_3.5.0-4.4_amd64.deb
   ```

> Note: Since you look like someone who should be fairly handy with this :), may I recommend you consider replacing the awful binary-only Broadcom card with one of the excellent Intel 6205 or 6300 half-mini-PCIe cards, which have fully open-source driver support in the *vanilla* kernel?

Comment: izx, thanks for the excellent reply. I had no idea I could install quantal kernels in precise. I will try the quantal kernels.

Comment: Also, I bought an Asus P8Z77-I motherboard which comes with the broadcom card. I can't replace it...

Comment: @PauloJ.Matos: It's even easier in that case! I did the same on my Asrock Z68 mITX a while back. Please see [this image](http://minus.com/lIhZyeRYGUw9L); carefully remove the two cable connectors by hand/fingernail, remove the one screw, and the card pops out. Replace with [one of these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-UNUSED-LENOVO-INTEL-WIFI-LINK-6205-CARD-T420-T420S-T520-T520S-60Y3253-/271009135750?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item3f19673c86), put the screw back and pop the cable connectors on. :D

Comment: izx, interesting. Didn't notice the wifi cards was so easy to remove when I assembled the PC. Are these cards sold by retail stores or you can only find them on ebay (and related) from old parts?

Comment: @PauloJ.Matos: I doubt you'll find them in retail brick-and-mortar stores, but they're available easily enough online, e.g. Amazon UK. Note that these are never packaged as retail, but sold as OEM, so even a new one will likely come in just a plastic shell/antistatic bag.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with the kernel package I downloaded from `xorg-edgers`. I then downloaded the quantal version of `bcmwl-kernel-source` from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/bcmwl-kernel-source), installed it and my wireless card worked immediately.