# Why am I unable to connect to wireless networks?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

Seems like a repeated question, but I am not able to find the answer within the question database, so I'll begin with what adapter I have:

`lspci | grep Network`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

`iwconfig eth1`:

```
eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

> EDIT 3: Wireless networks are detected, but unable to connect to any.
>
> EDIT 4: I have Dual booting into windows 7/XP and Ubuntu, Being both Windows able to >connect normally to any wireless.

Connecting to multiple WEP connections after configuring a Shared WEP Key / After updates seems to have broken the authentication, and it always keeps asking out for the key even though it's correct. I could connect to wireless perfectly with the base 12.04 installation with "Updates while installing".

I have the jockey Broadcom STA drivers activated.

What's wrong?

EDIT 4: Source of 1st edit: [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

EDIT: bcmwl kernel source is already to the latest version; linux-libc-dev, libc6-dev, linux-headers-generic, linux-headers are as well; blacklisting doesn't help either with ndiswrapper; removing with modprobe is not working either

EDIT 2: Reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source, as stated in [How do I get my BCM43228 card working in mainline kernel 3.4 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161316/how-do-i-get-my-bcm43228-card-working-in-mainline-kernel-3-4-or-higher?rq=1) outputs:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,301 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 185120 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bcmwl-kernel-source 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1 (using  .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic-pae/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

Comment: Did you try this one? ^^

Comment: bcmwl kernel source is already to the latest version; linux-libc-dev, libc6-dev, linux-headers-generic, linux-headers are as well; blacklisting doesn't help either with ndiswrapper; removing with modprobe is not working either

Comment: Please put that information in the question!

Comment: Can you test your laptop with another wireless card? Most wireless cards are miniPCIE, which is a common format. You can just swap it with a different one from another laptop to see that it's not a problem with your pcie bus.

Comment: I can use it in windows normally, which is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply reinstalling did the job.