# Trouble Installing Driver for BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n on ThinkPad X131e

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, thinkpad

This is my first time asking a question on here, bare with me.  So I have a brand new ThinkPad X131e with a Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n wireless card.  I currently have it dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7 Professional.  I am able to connect to wifi on Windows but not on Ubuntu.  When I try to install the driver with the "Install Additional Drivers" tool I get the the error

"Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: `/var/log/jockey.log`"

I have tried using the `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter` packages, neither of which have done any good.  I have tried uninstalling and re installing the `bcmwl-kernel-source` which did nothing. I have also been running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in between most of my changes and I have restarted my system multiple times.

I have also tried downloading the driver from Broadcom and following the readme file install the driver which did not work.

Please let me know if you know of anything that I haven't tried.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The bcmwl-kernel-source package (For Broadcom STA Drivers) before 12.10 sometimes does not install the Linux Headers which gives an installation error if doing it via Additional Hardware or Jockey

So install the following packages using,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev libc6-dev linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then reinstall `bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Also can have a read here - [How do I get my BCM43228 card working in mainline kernel 3.4 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161316/35775)  --> But this should not be the cause.

More details answer on all broadcom device - https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/35775

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Web-E.  I tried what you said and this is the result:

Comment: I tried what you said.  It was saying that the first list of packages you suggested were already installed.  I uninstalled them and then re installed them.  I uninstalled the bcmwl-kernel-source package and re installed it.  Right after it was done installing my computer gave me a message saying that there was some sort of error with a package and asked if I wanted to report it.  Running sudo modprobe wl yielded several "Fatal Errors" like Fatal: Module wl not found.  I looked at what was on your other two links and I had tried most of what was on there.

Comment: With KDE Neon, it is only  necessary to do:
`apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`