# Network Manager shows no WiFi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, broadcom

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, and this morning the Network Manager suddenly stopped showing any WiFi networks at all. One moment I was connected to a local wireless network, and the next I was not. Even worse, although the system recognises the wifi adapter, no wifi networks appear to show up.

"enp0s29u1u4c4i2" is an iPhone I am using as an access point to post this question, but usually there are only three devices (eno1, lo, wlp2s0). I am attaching the outputs of `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` and `iwlist scan`, all ran as `sudo`.

**ifconfig**

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:b6:fd:fc:9b:06  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1c00000-e1c20000 

enp0s29u1u4c4i2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:cf:9c:c6:b7:a0  
          inet addr:172.20.10.2  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::6eaa:eff8:b247:91b4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4361666 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:964896 (964.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2653 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2653 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:209742 (209.7 KB)  TX bytes:209742 (209.7 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:e6:02:40:ae  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:7
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s29u1u4c4i2  no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

**iwlist scan**

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s29u1u4c4i2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    No scan results
```

According to `lspci`, my network controller is a "Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n". I had some issues getting the OS to recognise it right after installing 16.04, but I solved them long ago by switching the default drivers. What can I do to start seeing wifi networks again?

Thanks!

Gonzalo

**EDIT**

As per Pilot6's suggestion, I am adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [1028:04a9]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1530 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:0011]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Also, here's the result of running the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) mentioned by @eldergeek: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23143090/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Kernel driver in use: wl ... Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161316/how-do-i-get-my-bcm43228-card-working-in-mainline-kernel-3-4-or-higher/162585

Comment: I edited my question according to Pilot6's  suggestion. I also attached the output of the wireless info script (http://paste.ubuntu.com/23143090/) mentioned by @elder-geek. I also tried to install the "Trusty" version of the bcmwl-kernel-source package (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bcmwl-kernel-source), but was met with the following error: "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic"

Comment: Oops! Wrong version. See my answer. You should probably remove the trusty installation. `sudo apt-get autoremove` will likely clean house for you.

Comment: Is `secure boot` disabled in your BIOS? What is REGDOMAIN set to in `/etc/default/crda`? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 3):

For 16.04 all you need to do is make sure restricted drivers are checked in your software and updates sources and issue the command `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Something strange's going on: when I left the office today, no networks were showing up. Now, just a couple of hours later and after coming back home from the office,  the wireless networks are showing up again. Is it possible that my problem is hardware and not software related? Is there a way to check this is the case?

I am attaching the wireless info script output produced after running it with the wifi adapter working correctly. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23143977/

Comment: Anything is possible. Without having specific details about the environments you are operating in and the differences between them, all any of us can do is provide our best guess. Broadcasting SSID's isn't even a requirement, and equipment can fail intermittently so if it's touch and go you might reeat the mini-pci card and at the same time insure that the antenna wires are properly attached and in good condition (not pinched in the access door)